# First R package - having trouble connecting to GitHub with usethis::use_github

Tags: r, git, macos, github, package

Working on first R package ever.
A data package for medical datasets for teaching.
Using the usethis workflow as described by Emil Hvitfelt
on Macbook Air with MacOS 10.15.3 Cataline

Project seems ok.

**R>** proj_sitrep()

working_directory: '/Users/peterhiggins/Documents/Rcode/medicaldata'
active_usethis_proj: '/Users/peterhiggins/Documents/Rcode/medicaldata'
active_rstudio_proj: '/Users/peterhiggins/Documents/Rcode/medicaldata'

I appear to be stuck on the GitHub connection
I have an account with repos, I have a PAT.
*but*

**R>** git_sitrep()
Git user

Name: 'Peter Higgins'
Email: 'higgi13425@yahoo.com'
Vaccinated: TRUE
usethis + git2r
Default usethis protocol: 'https'
git2r supports SSH: FALSE
Credentials: ''
GitHub
Personal access token: ''
User: 'higgi13425'
Name: 'Peter Higgins'
Repo
Path: '/Users/peterhiggins/Documents/Rcode/.git'
Local branch -> remote tracking branch: '' -> ''
GitHub pull request readiness
:information_source: This repo has neither 'origin' nor 'upstream' remote on GitHub.com.

*and*

**R>** use_github()
:heavy_check_mark: Checking that current branch is 'master'
Error: Detached head; can't continue

Not sure how to get past this problem.

Ideas welcome.
and any explanation of how I borked this also welcome.

thanks!